# API Data not showing on the click event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am retrieving the data from the Web API. It's now showing the items when I click the button Get By names.

My view code as follows.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="text1" value="" />
    <input type="button" name="name2" id="btn2" value="Get by names" />
    <ul id="names"> </ul>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn2").click(function () {
                $("#names").empty();
                $.getJSON("/api/Customer/", function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        $("<li>" + val + "</li>").appendTo($("#names"));

                    })
                })

            })


    </script>
```

The Web API controller data as follows:

```
 namespace theapis.Controllers
    {


        public class CustomerController : ApiController
        {
            private static List<string> studentnames = new List<string> { "Ammad", "Ali", "Khan" };

            public IEnumerable<string> GetvalueByIndex(){

             return customernames;
            }    

        public string Getnames(int id)
            {
                return customernames[2];
            }

        }
    }
```

The result should show the list.
Ammad 
Ali
Khan

Comment: does your ajax call hit to the controller method?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input .   Console showing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code.

You are specifying url to be :

```
$.getJSON("/api/Customer/"
```

and Web API by convention will go and look for `Get` method in the Customer controller while there is no method with name `Get` in the controller. You need to either change the name in the controller or look for way to call the action method with different name than convention.

A quick way is to rename the action method:

```
public string Get()
{
     private List<string> studentnames = new List<string> { "Ammad", "Ali", "Khan" };
     return customernames;
}
```

You are also missing parenthesis closing for `document.ready`. that piece of code would be like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            $("#names").empty();
                $.getJSON("/api/Customer/", function (data) {
                     $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                         $("<li>" + val + "</li>").appendTo($("#names"));

                     }); // $.each closing
                }); // $.getJSON closing

          }); // button click closing
 }); // document.ready closing
```